# Are Nodes "dynamic" variables?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

```
public CharList(CharList l) 
{
    // Whatever method your CharList provides to get the 
    // first node in the list goes here
    CharNode pt = l.head(); 

    // create a new head node for *this* list
    CharNode newNode = new CharNode();
    this.head = newNode;

    // Go through old list, copy data, create new nodes 
    // for this list.
    while(pt != null)
    {
        newNode.setCharacter(pt.getCharacter());
        pt = pt.getNext();
        if (pt != null)
        {
            newNode.setNext(new CharNode());
            newNode = newNode.getNext();
        }

    }
}
```

Ok, this is a copy constructor. What I don't quite understand is the two last lines.

```
            newNode.setNext(new CharNode());
            newNode = newNode.getNext();
```

Basically, the program should create set a node within a node so that it points to another element to the LinkedList. That's the what the first line should do and is doing; however, instead of defining the node inside the node, the line newNode = newNode.getNext(); just overwrites the node pointing to the other node rendering the first line useless. Is there something I am not getting?

```
pt = pt.getNext();
```

This line is okay since pt can be overwritten since pt is an element from the LinkedList we pass as an attribute, but the other two lines doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct. It is not overwrtiting it is just moving to next node and setting its values.

```
Step1 : Set next node using newNode.setNext(new CharNode());
Step2 : Move to next node using newNode = newNode.getNext();
Step 3 : Set value for next node newNode.setCharacter(pt.getCharacter());
```

Hope that clarifies.

Comment: exactly! 1+ for a well thought out answer!

Comment: ahhh, the value of the node can be different from the original? Because I was told that a node object contains a number that refers to another node object and a class object such as car.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the value of the node can be different from the original?" . Each node object contains a reference of next node, thats how you keep traversing from one node to next till you reach last